# Swing choose device to read ASCI string input from

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, device, hid

I have several devices that install as HID keyboard devices in most any operating system and, when used, send a string of text back, just like a keyboard.  Is there any way in a Swing app to listen only to a chosen device, ignoring the standard keyboard, and do it without a TextComponent to capture the data?  Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229513/disable-input-from-keyboard-and-allow-barcode-reader-only-using-java/8230693#8230693.

Comment: The first part of my question does seem to be similar to that question.  Any ideas on how to get a whole string of data without the TextComponent?

Comment: I don't think the close vote is appropriate in this case. The duplicate question only has one very vague answer, and was closed on accounts of being too vague, which this question isn't. Closing this question won't prevent duplication of content, neither is this question somehow bad in and of itself..

Comment: The only thing I could find is http://jusb.sourceforge.net/ – that *might* let you write your own "driver" for the devices in question, which would let you communicate with that device alone. The obvious downsides are that the library has been abandoned in 2003 and might not event work on current OSes, and that you'd have to implement all of the communication with that device instead of getting a neat bunch of Swing keystrokes.

Comment: I would believe that it is not feasible to select a keyboard device to listen to, at least not without rewriting a driver, but what about capturing keyboard input in Swing without a TextComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across via google, etc, here is the solution I finally found.
*(This is a solution to the second part of my question, how to capture input without a TextComponent).*

I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) and attached a KeyListener to my program. This allowed me to capture and parse input, albeit rather awkwardly.  I have yet to find a smoother solution to this.

*I may come back and add code to this. Please leave a comment if I have not yet done so and you would find it helpful*